# Stitching images together Opencv -Python

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

My program takes in an image and crops the image into seperate images according to the scale parameter, e.g. scale = 3 produces 9 images of equal size. I then work out mean rgb of each cropped image and set all pixel values in the image equal to the mean rgb value.

I am wondering how I can stich the cropped images back together to output one image? Which in this case would be a grid of nine different colours.

Here is my code:

```
# import packages
import numpy as np
import cv2
import dateutil
import llist
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import argparse

#Read in image
img = cv2.imread('images/0021.jpg')

scale = 3
#Get x and y components of image
y_len,x_len,_ = img.shape

mean_values = []
for y in range(scale):
    for x in range(scale):
        #Crop image 3*3 windows
        cropped_img=img[(y*y_len)/scale:((y+1)*y_len)/scale,
                          (x*x_len)/scale:((x+1)*x_len)/scale]

        mean_val=cv2.mean(cropped_img)
        mean_val=mean_val[:3]
        #Set cropped img pixels equal to mean RGB
        cropped_img[:,:,:] = mean_val

        cv2.imshow('cropped',cropped_img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)

        #Print mean_values array
        #mean_values.append([mean_val])
#mean_values=np.asarray(mean_values)
#print mean_values.reshape(3,3,3)
```

As it stands the nested for loop iterates over the image and outputs the images (which are just blocks of one colour) in the order that I want to stitch them together, but im not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: Don't "stitch" - it's harder. Create a new image with the desired final size, then copy each subimage into the appropriate region of the final image using [numpy's indexing capabilities](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html) (`cv2` images are just `numpy`a arrays)

Comment: @goncalopp how would I 'copy' each sub-image to a new image? It will have to take place in the for loop, and at each iteration a new sub image will be added to the output image.

Comment: Since you do `cropped_img = img[...]` and then operate on `cropped_image`, the original `img` will have been changed in place. Slicing in numpy arrays does not create new arrays. Thus, your stitching should have already been achieved.

Comment: @HannesOvrén Genius! How did i not see that, thank you:)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if such things exist in OpenCV, but in ImageMagick you can simply resize the image down to the tile-size (which will implicitly average the pixels) and the re-scale the image back up to the original size without interpolation - also called *Nearest Neighbour Resampling*. Like this:

[image]

```
# Get original width and height
identify -format "%wx%h" face1.jpg
500x529

# Resize down to, say 10x10 and then back up to the original size
convert face1.jpg -resize 10x10! -scale "${geom}"! out.jpg
```

[image]

Per your original, 3x3 becomes:

```
convert face1.jpg -resize 3x3! -scale "${geom}"! out.jpg
```

[image]

and 3x5 becomes:

```
convert face1.jpg -resize 3x5! -scale "${geom}"! out.jpg
```

[image]